# javascript files not running

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and I would use the method $.mobile.changePage() for the past page 1 to page 2.

the problem that the second page is displayed without running list of javascript.

```
$.mobile.changePage("../prestation_html/page2.html");
```

page two are separate, ie if you use a href then we add rel = 'external'

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653498/dynamically-add-pages-to-jquery-mobile-web-app/13656924#13656924

Answer (score 0):

Standard jQuery navigation uses AJAX to load the content of the body of the page you navigate to. The header is completely ignored, meaning that all scripts, links to scripts and stylesheets in the subsequent pages will be ignored.
You would need to make sure that all JS resources are loaded in the first page you load.
Be aware that `$(document).ready` will not work either on subsequent pages, you will need to bind to `'pageinit'` as described in the [jqm documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: then i should add the link of my code js 
`<script src="js/synchronisation_vers_tel/metre_a_jour_total.js"></script>
<script src="js/synchronisation_vers_tel/nombre_des_lignes.js"></script>` here

`
$("#page2").live('pageinit', function()
  {...}`

Comment: You should add the links to the header of your 1st page, and whatever code that needs to be run when you access the second page in $("#page2").live('pageinit', function() {...}